# jQuery: Is there any way to select multiple elements using an array selector?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select multiple elements using an **array selector**?

If so, what is the best way to do it? In my project, I need to use only array selectors.

This is my sample code:

```
<ul>
    <li>1<li>
    <li>2<li>
    <li>3<li>
    <li>4<li>
    <li>5<li>
</ul>
<a href="#">select</a>​

$('a').click(function(){
    var element = $('ul').find('li')[0]; // Instead is it possible $('ul').find('li')[0,3,4]? I know we can select finding each alone. But is there any shortcut?
    $(element).css({border:'1px solid red'});
})​
```

Comment: Just a little side note: since it's a 0-based index, the 5 in your [0,3,5] would mean that there are 6 elements instead of 5.

Comment: Is it possible to set a class name to the elements, so you can get them by $('.classname')

Comment: nope, it will vary according to the sectors and pages. thanks

Comment: @3gwebtrain You can add a custom method to the JS `Array` object. See my answer to get more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would give desired result. Simply filter by [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and use [inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

```
var arr = [0, 3, 5];
$('ul li').each(function() {
    if ($.inArray($(this).index(), arr) < 0)
        return;
    // Code here!
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
});
```

Basicly all the `<li>` are run through the each() and then I loop to check if given .index() is in given array. If they don't exist ( $.inArray() == -1 ) then I do a return; to skip execution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sexy way to do it: add a custom method to the JavaScript `Array` object as suggested in another answer.

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(indexes) {
    var array = new Array();
    for(var i=0; i<indexes.length; i++) {
        array.push(this[indexes[i]]);
    }
    return array;
};
```

To call it:

```
$('ul').find('li').filter([0,3,4]).anything();
```

Custom generic shortcut as you wished :)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/);

```
var indexArray = [1,3,4];
$('ul li').filter(function(index) {
    return jQuery.inArray($(this).index(), indexArray) > -1;
});
```

Also using [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) and [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
View [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/st3fan/DsN5d/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work (but not so good with performance):

```
$('ul li:nth-child(0),ul li:nth-child(2)');
```

Or this:

```
$('ul li:eq(0),ul li:eq(2)');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach of array also

```
arr = "013".split("");
arr.forEach(function(a,b){
    var element = $('li')[a]; 
    console.log(element);
    $(element).css({border:'1px solid red'});
});
```

Here's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ranganadh/t4CSH/1/)

Answer (score 0):

loop it

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var element = $('ul').children('li');
    var count = 0;
    for (x in element) {
        count++;
        if ((count == 0) || (count == 3) || (count == 5))
            x.css({ border: '1px solid red' });
    }
});
```